# Why isn't it filling the colour I selected?

Tags: materials, grease-pencil

[image]

I'm very new to Blender.

When I try to fill my object with the fill tool it doesn't fill the correct colour. It's meant to be a light pink but its coming out more of a dark purple

How to fix this?

Comment: hello, could you please show a screenshot?

Comment: Please have a look at the answer I posted yesterday and try the proposed solutions (i just made some edits specifically for Grease Pencil). If this doesn't help with the issue, please share us a file with the issue via [blend-exchange.com](https://blend-exchange.com) so that we can dig in.

Answer (score 1):

Be aware that, unless you set your viewport in a specific way, you will never see your textures' colors "as is" on your objects, there are many shading and lighting systems that can change the look of everything.

For example ; if you use the `Texture Paint` workspace, it will set your viewport to `Solid` shading with the color display mode into `Texture`, but you will still have the `Studio` lighting ON. You can switch it to `Flat` so to not have any shade on your object:

[image]

If you want to paint with a full material preview, you can switch your viewport shading to `Material Preview` or even `Rendered`, but then you have to accept that you won't see your textures "as is", but instead a representation of its effect in the shader and with your scene's surroundings and lighting. But you can switch between modes at any time, and you can have the Image Editor open on the side as well.

---

For Grease Pencil, more often that not you don't care about shading effects. So not only you should pay double attention to the above to avoid surprises, but you should also make sure you set the color management's `View Transform` to `Standard`. The `Filmic` used by default is designed for CGI with high bit depth and wide dynamic range post processing, which you don't need when only doing Grease Pencil and can mess up your color work.

[image]

Furthermore, to help you setup Blender for Grease Pencil, you can select the 2D Animation environment when creating a new file or on Blender's startup splash screen:

[image]

[image]

This environment will setup Blender for you in a single click.

Comment: Could be this, but sounds like he has something like multiply set as the blend mode. Or he could be switching the wrong colours to the wrong side.